# Can we get a promotional flyer?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Once the site hits public beta, I'd like to put up some signs around my school. It'd be nice if this were clever, eye-catching, and had a QR code.

Maybe one of the Stack Exchange design ninjas can make us a nice one-page flyer?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the "flyers" in this blog post:

[**Supporting Community Conferences**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/)

Once the site goes public, it should be easy enough to get some of these made up for distribution. You'll need to solidify the initial design and presentation of the site (the faq description, scope, and such). I don't know what the design schedule looks like, but once the site becomes a bit established, contact us at community@stackexchange.com with the text copy that will go into the design.